# How to use WITH Clause in the oracle forms

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

How to use WITH Clause in the oracle forms 10.1.2.0.2 with 10g database?
In the Button

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "In the Button" in your question?
In general, WITH clause can be used as follows :

```
with t as(select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual)
select * from t;
```

In your oracle forms button trigger : the equivalent of the above query can be as follows :

```
declare  
cursor c1 is select * from (select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual);  
begin  
    --your statements  
end;
```

Comment: Oh now i get the question.

Comment: Its not possible to use WITH clause in the Button's trigger, but you may use a cursor with the subquery which is in your WITH clause

Comment: Hi, i need your help can you please help me?

Comment: I have database block table columns , that has no values means not inserted any values , i have 2 columns in that block order_no,order_name , table name called xx_customer_details, so i need to create LOV on  order_no column using oracle table customer_details ,my requirement is i am selecting Order_no vlaues from LOV then need to populate in the order_name column automatically

Answer (score -1):

EX:

```
select employee_id, last_name, job_id, manager_id
from employees
START WITH employee_id = 101
CONNECT BY PRIOR manager_id = employee_id ;
```

Comment: He is asking for the with clause not the start with.